# flask many-to-many-relation leads to "Multiple classes found for path"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to define a many-to-many-relation in flask. (The two models are `User` and `Role`. Lateron I want to use them for Flask-Security.) So I followed http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#many-to-many-relationships and wrote

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = { 'useexisting': True }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    roles = relationship("RolesUsers", backref=db.backref("user", lazy='dynamic'))

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    __table_args__ = { 'useexisting': True }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)


class RolesUsers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles_users'
    __table_args__ = { 'useexisting': True }
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    role_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)
```

But I get the error

> Multiple classes found for path "RolesUsers" in the registry of this
>   declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.

I found out that the line

```
roles = relationship("RolesUsers", backref=db.backref("ma_user", lazy='dynamic'))
```

seems to be responsible for that.

You might ask why I use

```
__table_args__ = { 'useexisting': True }
```

That is because else I get the error

> Table 'user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify
>   'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing
>   Table object.

Maybe those two errors are hanging together? To my eye it looks like the Class is somehow called multiple times. But I have no clue how that might come. So how can I repair this?

Comment: It'd seem you've multiple similar class definitions. You're correct in that having to have extend existing is a symptom in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the usage of a Model Class for the association table. In the end

```
roles_users = db.Table(
    'ma_roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('ma_user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('ma_role.id'))
)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    roles = db.relationship(
        'Role',
        secondary=roles_users,
        backref=db.backref('user', lazy='dynamic')

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = "role"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

worked.